# Istio Virtual Service match uri and cookie not working

Tags: networking, kubernetes, microservices, istio

I have been trying to apply this virtual service yaml for my microservices:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nameko-notifyms
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - nameko-notifyms-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        cookie:
          regex: "^(.*?;)?(user=joe)(;.*)?"
      uri:
        exact: /hello
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nameko-notifyms
        port:
          number: 8000
```

Using the code block above, after curl-ing the uri, there is not traffic going into the pod.

If I comment out the information as shown in the code block below:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nameko-notifyms
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - nameko-notifyms-gateway
  http:
  - match:
#    - headers:
#        cookie:
#          regex: "^(.*?;)?(user=joe)(;.*)?"
    - uri:
        exact: /hello
    route:
    - destination:
        host: nameko-notifyms
        port:
          number: 8000
```

The traffic is directed to the pod, which can be shown in the image below:
[image]

Postman setting as below:
[image]

Comment: what curl are you using for test?

Comment: @VasilyAngapov I am actually using Postman, will add the screenshot with my cookies.

Comment: Might `regex` string be wrong, give a try: `^(.*?;)?(user=joe)(;.*)?$`.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the problem is old but still actual so here the solution :
The problem come from the regex the first block `;` is not optional.

Here the corrected regex.

```
"^(.*;?)?(user=joe)(;.*)?"
```

Full detail here : https://regex101.com/r/CPv2kU/3